# Get user table row information after login

Tags: php, html, session, mysqli

How do I request all user information after user is logged in? I want to make a sidebar where the user that's logged in can see his information that's stored in the database.

Just an easy code will be great so I can echo the information everywhere like in the HTML:

```
//WORKS//<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['username']); ?>
//NOT WORKING//<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['firstname']); ?>
//NOT WORKING//<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['lastname']); ?>
//NOT WORKING//<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['email']); ?>
```

DATABASE: USERS > ID - USERNAME - FIRSTNAME - LASTNAME - EMAIL.

This is going to be the detail page. Don't mind the HTML.

my php code

```
<?php
// Initialize session
session_start();
include("config.php");

// If session variable is not set, redirect to login page
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Homepagina</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Hi, <b><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['username']); ?></b>. Welcome to our site.</h1>
        </div>
        <p><a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-danger">Uitloggen!</a></p>
    </body>
</html>


// THIS IS THE LOGIN.PHP
            if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                // Bind result variables
                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username, $hashed_password);
                if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                    if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                        /* Password is correct, so start a new session and
                        save the username to the session */
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                        $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;      
                        header("location: homepagina.php");
                    }
```

Comment: tried doing a select from user table where user id = userid? I'm assuming you store the user id in the session array, yes?

Comment: @AkintundeOlawale I don't know how to write that properly. I have tried userID but it's not working?

Comment: Then add the query you've tried to your question. That'll help point out your mistake(s)

Comment: Show the code where you are filling the $_SESSION .. you should be able to change the code there so firstname, lastname and email are within the session data.  Something like `$_SESSION['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];`

Comment: @RaymondNijland code added

Answer (score -1):

By *request* user information, I am assuming that you mean request the database for additional user information to display in your side-pannel that you were talking about. I don't see any code for the side-pannel, so I am assuming you have this down, and just need the actual database information in order to display it in the side-pannel.

What you want to do is to `query` the database with a `SELECT` statement, asking for 'everying' `*`. You then fetch the information in an array format, `mysqli_fetch_array()`. You then make PHP variables containing the different database values. Either by session or something else. The way that works, is like with any array. You ask for which index you'd like to retrieve.

Example of how to extract data from the database:

```
<?php
//$conn is your database connection variable from config.php
//If your connection variable is named something else, change it accordingly

$sessionUser=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION['id']);

$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$sessionUser'";
$result_set=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($conn, $result_set);

//row variables from your table (given that the rows you gave are correct)
$id=$row['id'];
$username=$row['username'];
$fistname=$row['firstname'];
$lastname=$row['lastname'];
$email=$row['email'];

//row variables as session variables
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
$_SESSION['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
$_SESSION['lastname'] = $row['lastname'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
?>
```

I hope this is pretty straight forward.

***PLEASE NOTE*** that I am using *id* in your session instead of *username* in order to extract data from the database, so you will have to set this as your session variable instead of *username* upon login. The reason for this, is because I am not entirely sure whether username is a unique identifier or not. If it is, you can change it back to fit your logic accordingly.

Now, it's difficult for me to give a 100% accurate copy paste version, since I feel like your code is incomplete, neither is it in my or your interest really. The best would be for you to *understand* what I am doing and be able to implement it on your own, and know what you're doing, instead of copy pasting things around without having a clue.

If you need anything elaborated, you can ask, but I am not going to code your application for you. However, I also feel like this is a very simple matter that Google could have easily solved for you. Just my 2 cents.

You also already set *username* as a session variable once, which means you already extracted user information once in order to do that. How come you aren't able to use the same approach? Or simply set the rest of the row variables into session in the same place? This is why I felt like your code is incomplete, and why you might not 100% understand what is going on, or what you are doing. Unless you provide that information, it's going to be hard to help you 100%, and make you *understand*, i.e. the piece of code / file where you set your *username* session variable.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Can you edit this code so I can copy and just paste this in my code above?

Comment: Should be copy pastable now. I tried to follow along with your mysqli syntax, but I haven't personally used mysqli syntax before, but I hope it's correct.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted by the way? This is what you were looking for? It's functional by the information you gave in your question.

Comment: What kind of errors are you running into @Je Boy Abi? See edited answer? I changed your username logic to go by id instead, but still parse your username as a session variable in case you need it like you used to. The reason for this, is because I am unsure whether username is unique. Normally, you'd always go by an id, because you are sure it's 100% unique. I also didn't change anything in your login PHP, assuming that bit works, since you only asked for how you get all the user information, or what do you mean by *request*, specifically?